# Python Fastapi raise KeyboardInterrupt when reloading

Tags: python, fastapi

Recently, I have started a new project with Fastapi. I wrote this code below in my 'main.py':

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette_wtf import CSRFProtectMiddleware



app = FastAPI(
    middleware=[
        Middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key='496896fb2b2750e60d31a47b4150b13b'),
        Middleware(CSRFProtectMiddleware, csrf_secret='94714a7de2c8988abc4f57cdb53d3ef3')
    ]
)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

As I'm in development process, I'm using `uvicorn main:app --reload` but when I reload application with 'Ctrl+S' or save modifications, I have severals KeyboardInterrupt() errors raised like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\jeremy\OneDrive - Capgemini\Desktop\Python\SPIRIT_SLA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 78, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "c:\Users\jeremy\OneDrive - Capgemini\Desktop\Python\SPIRIT_SLA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I never had this before with my other projects. Any idea how to solve it ? I've already changed my python interpreter (from 3.11 to 3.12.2), try to upgrade package to last version, but nothing changed...

Comment: Did you try using hypercorn instead of uvicorn

Comment: Do you have a bare `try`/`except` (i.e. not catching any named exceptions, such as `except Exception:`) in your code? It could be that you're catching a `KeyboardInterrupt` that is meant to be handled by uvicorn.

Comment: Hi, I tried hypercorn. Working fines and no more KeyboardInterrupt raised but less logging... I prefer uvicorn. And I don't have any try/except in my python files that could be explain these error.